# How to parse a list of xml paths in python?

Tags: python, xml, list, path

How could I parse a list of xml paths in python?

For example, I have a list like this:

```
list=['path1.xml','path2.xml','path3.xml']
```

For a single xml I can use:

```
from xml.dom import minidom                                          
xmldoc = minidom.parse('path1.xml')
```

But how could i parse each one of them?

Comment: how would you iterate over any list?

Comment: @Fransin please accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a loop:

```
 from xml.dom import minidom
 list=['path1.xml','path2.xml']
 for item in list:
     xmldoc = minidom.parse(item)
```

This will iterate through each item in your list and do something with that item.

Read more about it [here](http://www.diveintopython.net/file_handling/for_loops.html) 'iterating with for loops.'

I recommend using descriptive variable names, but kept yours the same as your example for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Using `lst` is descriptive also and a lot better idea than using list

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, but was keeping with OP's own example.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a loop:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xmls = ['path1.xml','path2.xml','path3.xml']
for x in xmls:
    xmldoc = minidom.parse(x)
```

BTW, do not use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: thanks! it works.I know, I just used the name list to show its property.

Comment: Great, you can mark it as the solution then :) As for the variable name, I know but it's generally discouraged to use such "standard" words for variables.